# Feature Request: Verified Users

Tags: feature-request

I want to suggest a feature i.e. verifying some trusted users and giving them a badge.This will help the new users to trust the good answers given by them.

Comment: What would "trusted user" mean? And why would this be any different from using reputation points to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a very bad idea.

When looking at answers, you should always pay attention to the content, not just who is posting it.  Experienced users can be wrong, and newer users can still provide very good answers.  Having the reputation system already adds bias, which you could argue is somewhat detrimental to fair voting based on content.  The reputation system is crucial to the gamification of the site though, and I don't see why we would want to add another level of something similar to reputation with this "verification".

Ideally the new users will trust the highly voted answers, which should also ideally be the correct ones due to the voting system.  In the best case scenario, reputation doesn't play in to determining quality of answers, they stand on their own.  This would influence that in a bad way in my opinion.

Comment: Plus how do you determine if someone is a "trusted user"? If it is based on metrics that are not related to the site, then this is very problematic since good answers come from a wide variety of people with wide varieties of expertise, education, background, field, career, etc. I am interested to hear what the OP is thinking here

Comment: @AaronStevens Plus even with any of those metrics, it doesn't stop you from being wrong.  I'm active here and it's nice that there's some indicator of that with my reputation.  I wouldn't want to be implicitly _trusted_ though.  I make mistakes and I wouldn't want people to trust what I'm saying implicitly.

Comment: Hmmm... I accept I was wrong.

Comment: @Sarcasm All good.  Meta is the place to bring up these things, and downvotes/upvotes here don't actually have any effect on reputation anyways.

Comment: @Sarcasm you were not “wrong”. Your suggestion is just not terribly useful as the site already has “reputation” as a proxy for what you want to implement.